# do while loop converting temperature php not looping

Tags: php, loops, temperature

Hi this is a table converting celsius to kelvin and fahrenheit, I am just wondering why my code does not loop :( it only displays the first two lines and stops. Thank you!

```
<?php 
$celsius = 100;
$stop_kelvin = 0;

print '<table>';
print '<tr><th>Degrees Celsius(C)</th><th>Kelvin(K)</th><th>Degrees Fahrenheit(F)</th></tr>';
while ($kelvin <= $stop_kelvin) {
$fahr = ($celsius*1.8) + 32;
$kelvin = $celsius + 273;
print"<tr><td>$celsius</td><td>$kelvin</td><td>$fahr</td></tr>";
$fahr += 1;
}
print '</table>';

?>
```

Comment: What is the value of $kelvin when the while statement first runs?

Comment: the value of $kelvin is initially the value calculated based on when $celsius is 100 @SamM

Comment: That initialization isn't in the code you posted. See answers below. You are getting random values in $kelvin without initialization.

Comment: Use do while...loop instead of above..and what is ur code logic

Answer (score 1):

In your code, $kelvin variable is not initialized. Also, please re-think your loop logic.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you havent initialized $kelvin; because of which $kelvin is taking some random values. 
After first loop the value of $kelvin becomes 373 and in your loop it is `$kelvin <= $stop_kelvin` means the condition is false and it jumps out of the loop